# Retrieving Users Account

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have this app which gets users data from the database using the username they logged in with. The user name is passed once they login to the page which retrieves their account information. The app crashes saying retrieving the information was wrong, can anyone help?

The database code

```
public Cursor RetriveLoggedUsersData (DatabasOpperations DBOpp, String Username){
    SQLiteDatabase SQDB = DBOpp.getReadableDatabase();
    String[] Coloumns = {TableData.TableInfo.FIRSTNAME, TableData.TableInfo.LASTNAME, TableData.TableInfo.EMAIL, TableData.TableInfo.USERNAME, TableData.TableInfo.PASSWORD, TableData.TableInfo.IMAGE};
    String Where = TableData.TableInfo.USERNAME + " LIKE ?";
    String Argument[] = {Username};
    Cursor Cur = SQDB.query(TableData.TableInfo.TABLE_NAME, Coloumns, Where, Argument, null, null, null);
    Log.d("DatabaseOperations", "Success, User Retrived");
    return Cur;
}
```

The code which wants to retrieve the data

```
Username = getIntent().getExtras().getString("Username");

DatabasOpperations DB = new DatabasOpperations(Contx);
        Cursor Cur = DB.RetriveLoggedUsersData(DB, Username);
        DBFName = Cur.getString(0);
        DBLName = Cur.getString(1);
        DBEmail = Cur.getString(2);
```

Comment: When your app has a crash, the logcat output is relevant when posting your question so it becomes easier to track the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to move the Cursor to the first position by making a call to `moveToFirst()`, and also check the return value to make sure there is at least one row in the Cursor.  Also be sure to close your Cursor:

```
Cursor Cur = DB.RetriveLoggedUsersData(DB, Username);
if (Cur.moveToFirst()) {
    DBFName = Cur.getString(0);
    DBLName = Cur.getString(1);
    DBEmail = Cur.getString(2);
}
Cur.close();
```

Comment: thank you ever so much, it worked!

Comment: @RexDough No problem!  Be sure to include the stack trace next time if it's crashing!

Comment: ok thanks and will do